# txt file not found using glassfish 4.1.1 on netbeans ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, netbeans, glassfish

I am using netbeans 8.1 with glassfish server. I had also used tomcat. The problem is: I need to generate a txt file from a servlet but this txt file doesn't appear anywhere in project folder, not even in server folder.

Comment: how you generate it can you show us your code please?

Answer (score 0):

public void saveFile() throws IOException{

```
    PrintWriter writer;
    try{

        writer = new PrintWriter(this.file_route);
        String line = "";

        for(Event event : events_list){

           line =  event.getName() +
                    "," + event.getDescription() + "\n";

           writer.write(linea);

        }

    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```